# com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection: [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 60000 milliseconds

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, datastax-enterprise

We have a Spark streaming app built using DSE and Kafka. Cluster specifications : 3 analytics, 2 cassandra, and 1 Kafka nodes. All are ec2 instances. For streaming, we use Spark streaming with Kafka. After we downgraded the number of Kafka nodes from 3 to 1, we are facing one error :

ERROR 2017-03-20 06:13:54,690 com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection: [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 60000 milliseconds

Although if I try to connect to the same kafka instance from my local machine, it consumes data.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection timeout is Kafka problem. I know that com.datastax.driver.core is Cassandra related package.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:
   if all are in ec2 instances try connecting through private IP. much faster and cost effective with AWS.

Comment: Tried with private ip's,publics ip's, public dns and localhost too but nothing helped.